# How can I make my validation more idiomatic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

After using a few validation libraries I finally decided to roll my own implementation, since none of the libraries behaved the way I wanted. The code below works fine, but I think it's not very idiomatic. The function body is huge and should probably be refactored into smaller chunks.

I am sure there are many ways to improve my code, but I am asking for specific advice on how to break up the large function into smaller functions, so that the code is easier to understand. Obviously I want to add a lot more validation functions, and I don't want to create a bunch of spaghetti.

The validation should happen on `blur` of an element. By inserting and removing `div`s the user is notified of the problem.

The validation function:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    live_validate: function() {
      return this.each(function() {

        var inputs = $('input', $(this));

        inputs.blur(function() {
          var el = $(this);
          el.siblings('div.feedback').remove();

          if(el.hasAttr('required') && el.val() == '') {
            el.after('<div class="feedback feedback-error">must be present</div>');
            return;
          }    

          if(el.hasAttr('minlength') && el.val().length < el.attr('minlength')) {
            el.after('<div class="feedback feedback-error">is too small</div>');
            return;
          }

          // no validation returned; all good.
          el.filter(":visible").after('<div class="feedback feedback-ok"></div>');

        });

      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This is a quick helper I made to check if an attribute is present. I need to know if the attribute is present at all. Is there a better way to do this?

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {
   return (this.attr(name) !== undefined && this.attr(name) !== false);
};
```

Finally, call the validator on the form I want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form.new_user").live_validate();

}
```

Comment: Your approach for a simple validator doesn't look too bad to me, in all honesty.

Comment: Would it still look not bad if I added validators for equal-ness, a remote JSON call for existing values, numericality, and so forth? I'm worried it grows into a hairball by adding those inside the main function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate each validator in it's own function, separating each logic in another function.

```
(function($) {
  var validators = {
    required: function(el) {
        // Validation code...
    },
    minlength: function(el) {
        // Validation code...
    } // you can add more validators here..
  };
  $.fn.extend({
    live_validate: function(enabledValidators) {
      return this.each(function() {

        var inputs = $('input', $(this));

        inputs.blur(function() {
          var el = $(this);
          el.siblings('div.feedback').remove();
          var hasErrors = false;

          $(enabledValidators).each(function() {
             var result = validators[this](el);
             if(result !== true) {
               el.after('<div class="feedback feedback-error">' + result + '</div>');
               hasErrors = true;
             }
          });

          if(!hasErrors) {
            el.filter(":visible").after('<div class="feedback feedback-ok"></div>');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

What I did here was to encapsulate each validation in it's own funcion. It always receives de element and returns true if it's valid or a string with the error if it's invalid. I also added an enabledValidators to be able to pass which validators you want to run (you could remove this and execute all the validators always if you want, or only use all the validators if nothing was passed). So you would call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form.new_user").live_validate(["required", "minlength"]);
}
```

Comment: Not bad, it's a definite improvement. I am not fond of passing the array with options. I really want to parse the HTML5 form attributes, so that the form is validated by modern browsers. But the encapsulation is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, there's no need to pass the options if you don't want, just iterate over all the validators instead.